# Shopware theme commands returns error: E_USER_DEPRECATED

Tags: shopware6

I have a local installation of Shopware 6.5.7.1. Have created a new theme the usually way (bin/console theme:create). All worked well.

But, if I run "theme:refresh" or "theme:compile" I get an error:

```
INFO      [php] User Deprecated: Since shopware/core : Method "Shopware\Core\Content\Media\Pathname\UrlGenerator::Shopware\Core\Content\Media\Pathname\UrlGenerator::getAbsoluteMediaUrl()" is deprecated and will be removed in v6.6.0.0. Use "Use AbstractUrlGenerator instead" instead.
[
  "exception" => ErrorException {
    #message: "User Deprecated: Since shopware/core : Method "Shopware\Core\Content\Media\Pathname\UrlGenerator::Shopware\Core\Content\Media\Pathname\UrlGenerator::getAbsoluteMediaUrl()" is deprecated and will be removed in v6.6.0.0. Use "Use AbstractUrlGenerator instead" instead."
    #code: 0
    #file: "./vendor/shopware/core/Framework/Feature.php"
    #line: 201
    #severity: E_USER_DEPRECATED
```

I'm using Mamp Pro and have tried with both PHP 8.1 and 8.2. My previous theme, SW 6.5.6 and PHP 8.1, worked without any issue...
Anyone knows how to fix this?

UPDATE 1.
If I run "plugin:refresh" it seems to work - but I get a few notice like this:

```
Failed to initialize global composer: Composer could not find the config file: /Users/magnus/Sites/localhost/bytadiskbank/var/cache/composer/composer.json
```

Comment: Yeah the notices are a bit annoying but can basically be ignored if you not porting a plugin or so - cool that you solved it and thanks for the updates, you can post this as an answer and self-accept it as well, so the question is marked solved :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SOLVED. Well, always talk to the cat :). Problem solved. If adding "--no-debug" to the command, everything works.

Comment: Great - Please accept your answer :-)

Comment: Shouldn't that be the other way like a `--verbose` switch vs. default silent mode @Alex ?

Comment: Yes, it's a bit strange that the debug messages come by default. Not sure if that only happens with APP_ENV=dev

Comment: It depends on the `php.ini` error logging level afaik. `E_USER_DEPRECATED` is not an error, but a "deprecated" notice placed consciously by a developer – it means something will be removed in the future. It could also be Monolog needs to be configured not to show deprecated notices.